# Active Directory LDAP bind via X.509 client certificate authentication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2016

I'd like to enable a user to perform a LDAP bind to active directory by using a x.509 client certificate to authenticate. I'm struggling to understand how to put the pieces together.

From the MS Article [here:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/8e73932f-70cf-46d6-88b1-8d9f86235e81)

> If the client establishes the SSL/TLS-protected connection by means of connecting on a protected LDAPS port, then the connection is considered to be immediately authenticated (bound) as the credentials represented by the client certificate.

I'm concluding that if a client attempts to connect to a LDAPS enabled server on port 636 they can optionally present their client certificate as part of the TLS handshake. If they do, the identity interpolated from that client certificate can be sufficient to authenticate the user and complete the connection (bind) Is this accurate?

Assuming my understanding is correct, I still don't understand the following:

What mechanism does active directory use to 'map' a client certificate to a user? Is the CN matching a domain username sufficient? Or does the client certificate need to be added to some attribute in the user's object in the directory such as the [Alt-Security-Identities attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-altsecurityidentities)?

What determines which CAs the server will trust as an issuer of client certificates? Is it possible to have an entirely separate CA for client certificates from that of the servers trust chain? This (somewhat dated) [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2980.ldap-over-ssl-ldaps-certificate.aspx#Enabling_LDAPS_for_Client_Authentication) states:

> The client must be using a certificate from a CA that the LDAP server trusts

but I'm unclear as to how that trust is set up.

Answer (score 2):

That would be using same attribute mapping mechanisms as smart card authentication. The standard way is to have the user UPN in SAN, mapped to the userPrincipalName attribute. Other attributes could be used, but that is not common: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-certificate-requirements-and-enumeration

I don’t know whether LDAP will accept certificate only from CA in the NTAUTH store (which is required for smart cards), or any trusted CA. Easy to test though.